# How to create the pagination correctly?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this query to retrieve the posts:

```
<?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$the_query = new WP_Query(array('category__not_in' => array(8), 'paged' => $paged)); ?>
```

and this pagination:

```
global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
```

copied from: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

But it does works, the paginations `1 2 3 4 5 6` always have the same links (after i click on a page the first time), and the records are not shown correctly....because I have 13 pages (I read it from `max_num_pages`) of results, but after the second i do not see any other results.

Could someone help me?

Comment: I could be missing the obvious, but if you replace $wp_query->max_num_pages with $the_query->max_num_pages does it change anything? Also, get_query_var will also use the globalized query, not the custom $the_query you created, so that might cause problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
$wp_query->max_num_pages
```

by this

```
$the_query->max_num_pages
```